# Adding attribute to nodes by using networkX

Tags: python, igraph, networkx

I have calculated the optimal number of networks for each node by using igraph, and here is the code I used.

```
import igraph
g = igraph.Graph.Read_Ncol('data.txt')
dendrogram = g.community_edge_betweenness()
clusters = dendrogram.as_clustering()
membership = clusters.membership
```

And now I would like to use the `set_node_attributes` function in networkX to tag each node with its number of communities. So if I run `nx.get_node_attributes(g,'counts')` it should produce

```
{123: 2,
 124: 3,
 125: 4 and so on} where "123" is a node and "2" is the count associated
```

I am thinking to use a for loop here but am not sure how to get started.

**EDITED:**

```
membership
#output: 
[2,
 3,
 4]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming `membership` is a dictionary with nodes as keys and counts as value, then based on the version of networkx you are using (I am using v2.1), check the syntax of `set_node_attributes`, for [version 2.](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.set_node_attributes.html)1, it is `set_node_attributes(G, values, name=None)`,
so you simply do

```
nx.set_node_attributes(G, membership, 'counts')

print G[123]['count']
#output 2
```

Then use `get_node_attributes` to extract the same dictionary, [like this](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.get_node_attributes.html#networkx.classes.function.get_node_attributes)

```
attribute_dict = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'counts')

print attribute_dict[123]
#output : 2
```

**Update** : Assuming `membership` is a list of counts, then it will be in the same order as `G.nodes()`, so we can

```
node_list = list(G.nodes())

count_dict = { k:v for k,v in zip(node_list,membership)}
```

then do

```
nx.set_node_attributes(G, count_dict, 'counts')
```

Comment: Guess 'membership' is not a dictionary here. Should I write a for loop to create one with nodes as keys and counts as value?